# Can Not Locate Any File In Applications Via Terminal

Tags: terminal, cd, locate

I am trying to access my Android SDK in my Applications folder on my Mac via Terminal. However, While I can access Applications, I can not access my SDK nor any other file in Applications.

What Am I doing incorrectly?

I use the "cd fileName" to access each level, yet, nothing beyond Applications, "apparently exists" beyond applications.

??

Answer (score 1):

There are two Applications folders on your Mac. I think you are in the wrong one.

Use the command `ls` to see what files are in the Applications folder you are in. I believe it will come back with no results. This is the one at

```
/Users/username/Applications
```

The Applications folder you are looking for is located at

```
/Applications
```

To get to this use the command `cd ..` three times which will bring you back to your root directory. You can also cd directly to your root folder with the command `cd /` If you want to find out where you are at any time use the 'please write directory' command `pwd` which will give you the file path to your location.

Then cd into the correct Applications folder with the command

```
cd Applications
```

Try using the `ls` command there to see if contains the file you are looking for. You should then be able to `cd` into your Android SDK

If you want to find out why you have two Applications folders check out [this website](http://www.tuaw.com/2010/12/03/mac-101-the-two-applications-folders/) which explains it pretty well.